# LAST_INSERT_ID not working on UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, last-insert-id

if I use this SQL:

```
UPDATE formulare SET EV_id=59, EV_status=5 WHERE EV_id=57 AND ID_uziv=12;SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I will get `0` as last insert id.
I'm using php `mysqli_insert_id` and here is said that:

```
The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query 
on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. 
If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement 
or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, 
this function will return zero.
```

my table `formualre` has `auto increment` column, so I don't know wher the problem is

Comment: update will not give you the last insert id.It only gives you the count of records updated.Last insert id is only for insert

Comment: `last_` **insert** `_id` should tell you anything you need to know. There was nothing inserted. So there is no ID returned.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you cite ?

Comment: documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) and my response to your answers is under the @dystroy answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't work if **no** new auto increment value  was created.

The solution is something like this:

```
UPDATE formulare
  SET EV_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(59),
    EV_status=5
  WHERE EV_id=57
    AND ID_uziv=12;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Note: I guess, that `EV_id` is the auto_increment primary key.

Otherwise you should do a query like:

```
UPDATE formulare
  SET key_col = LAST_INSERT_ID(key_col),
    EV_id=59,
    EV_status=5
  WHERE EV_id=57
    AND ID_uziv=12;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: It's also very helpful while doing `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query to get `id` when row is updated. Even documentation mentions about this trick. :)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) :

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, **0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value**, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

As your update didn't create a new record, it didn't generate any AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: ok, but why there is this `...If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement...` ?

Comment: This sentence is curious, but maybe the author was referring to [this kind of statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE query updates the existing record, it doesn't return any new ID.

```
mysqli_insert_id retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the        
previous query (usually INSERT).
```

There was no INSERT query, that's the reason, you won't get any Id after executing UPDATE query.

For more info, refer [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)